# How to correctly send custom message to server after some event in OMNET++

Tags: tcp, omnet++, sendmessage, inet

I have a problem with the message, which I send from my custom TCP client app service to the server (also with my custom app layer service) in OMNET++ simulation.

My TCPCustomClientApp service is created from TCPBasicCientApp service from INET framework. I overrode some methods like initialize, handleMessage, socketEstablished and I added some helper methods for my needs.

I have my custom message, now, after some trigger from a network, I would like to send this message to the server encapsulated to GenericAppMsg.

this is my code:

```
...
if (trigger){
    connect(); // connect to the server - 3way TCP handshake

    auto customMsg = new MyCustomMessage();
    customMsg->set ...
    msgBuffer.push_back(customMsg); // list with messages
}
```

then in method `socketEstablished(int connId, void *ptr)` I have this code for sending:

```
    auto msg = new GenericAppMsg();
    msg->setByteLength(requestLength);
    msg->setExpectedReplyLength(replyLength);
    msg->setServerClose(false);
    msg->setKind(1); // set message kind to 1 = TCP_I_DATA (definned in enum TcpStatusInd in TCPCommand.msg)
    msg->encapsulate(msgBuffer.front()); // encapsulate my custom message into GenericAppMsg
    sendPacket(msg);
```

The problem is, that when this message comes to the server kind is 3 = ESTABLISHED.

What am I missing? Is this sending wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `kind` field is a freely usable field in messages that can be used for anything, but you should be aware that there is absolutely no guarantee that you will get the same value for the `kind` field on the receiving side. This is considered meta data that is bound to the actual message object. Downwards in the various lower OSI layers the packet can be aggregated or fragmented so the identity of the message object is not kept.

In short, exchanging data in the `kind` field is safe only if it is used for the communication between two modules that are directly connected. If there is anything between them, you cannot be sure whether the message is forwarded, or recreated with the same content or that some modules on the path between them decides to use the `kind` field to something else.

Anything that you want to pass to the other end must be encapsulated *inside* the message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My custom server app service extends this ones  https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/applications/tcpapp/TcpGenericServerApp.cc  ... see handleMessage method.

Comment: I still can't make it. Couldn't you help me with an example of how to send a message to a server, please? I'm desperate about it.